# Can't open google map

Tags: ios, swift, google-maps, deep-linking, applinks

I use the following swift code and but it print "Can't use comgooglemaps://" everytime. I test it in real iphone7 and google map app has been installed.
Please kindly help.

```
if UIApplication.shared.canOpenURL(URL(string:"comgooglemaps://")!) {
   UIApplication.shared.open(URL(string:"comgooglemaps://?center=40.765819,-73.975866&zoom=14&views=traffic")!)
} else {
   print("Can't use comgooglemaps://")
}
```

Comment: @AndreaMugnaini yes

Answer (score 8, accepted):

It's mandatory to define the key `LSApplicationQueriesSchemes`, hence inside your `Info.plist` you should have the following:

[image]

If you want to change it manually you may add this:

```
<key>LSApplicationQueriesSchemes</key>
<array>
    <string>comgooglemaps</string>
</array>
```

You may check the official documentation at [Step 7: Declare the URL schemes used by the API](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/ios-sdk/start#step_7_declare_the_url_schemes_used_by_the_api):

> Beginning with iOS 9 and Xcode 7, apps must declare the URL schemes that they intend to open, by specifying the schemes in the app's Info.plist file. The Google Maps SDK for iOS opens the Google Maps mobile app when the user clicks the Google logo on the map, and your app therefore needs to declare the relevant URL schemes.

Answer (score 0):

Add to your Custom IOS Target Properties

```
Queried URL Schemes -> comgooglemaps
```

[image]